# Spaces are switching unexpectedly

Tags: macos, spaces

I'm having an issue where my spaces keep randomly switching without me doing anything.

I haven't managed to work out any sort of consistency to the behaviour yet so impossible to reproduce, but I'm trying to find out if anyone's had the same problem and knows how to fix it?

I'm running OSX 10.10.1 (Yosemite) on a Late 2008 aluminium MacBook.

Comment: Are you by any chance using MS Office?

Comment: Ctrl + Arrows change which space you're in - any chance you're doing that?

Comment: Nope, not using MS Office. It happens when I'm not touching the keyboard at all.

Comment: You should accept Lynn's answer. Not quite sure why a setting like that should change unexpectedly behind a users back...

Comment: Related: [window not in focus and sometimes jumping back to previous Space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/444722/22781).

Answer (score 3):

System Preferences > Mission Control > uncheck Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use