# Switching between Spaces in macOS: window not in focus and sometimes jumping back to previous Space

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

Stranger things are happening with macOS 12 (on every version) on my MacBook Air M1. When I switch between Spaces (and with a window in full-screen mode), then the window in the next Space is not in focus when switching, and sometimes when moving quickly with a swipe, for example, from 3D Space to 1st, the system takes me back to 3D in half a second.

I've looked all over and can't figure out what could be the problem.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: no. it is disappearing after reboot, but after 15-20 mins returning. i reinstalled mac os but bug is still there(

Comment: Related: [Spaces are switching unexpectedly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/163081/22781).

Comment: Its funny that they removed this feature, it was so nice on previous OS versions.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a big issue with window not being in focused when switching spaces after having updated my mac to Ventura, hence stumbling across this thread.

For anyone who's still having this issue, I've found an indirect workaround by accident today. And after having tested for awhile it seems to fix this issue well. Try download [AutoRaise](https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise) or [Yabai Window Manager](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) from Github and see if it solves your issue (I'm only using the first one for now).

Basically what it does is it'll focus on the windows that your mouse is pointing at, which is good for people who have multiple things open in the same window for multi-tasking, and you'd need to click the window to have it focused first before you can do anything with it, which is extremely annoying, and that's the point of these 2 apps. They just happen to also fix the full-screen space not being focused.

Comment: Maybe give the link to the github?

Comment: @Thinkr Didn't wanna make it look like a commercial. But yeah bro, please try https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise

Comment: @Thinkr And this one is for Yabai. I heard it's more versatile if you configure it through command line. Haven't tried it, though:  https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Might be nice to include that in the question. ;)

Comment: Ok but what about when you have multiple windows open and you want to mouse over one window to scroll but still type in another window.  That is what you could use to do.

Comment: @traisjames I'm still only using AutoRaise atm, but you can set a key to temporarily achieve what you want. You can also set a key to 'toggle' that if you don't want to keep holding the key.